# Can not train from text file in fasttext. Getting ValueError: Empty vocabulary

Tags: python-3.x, word-embedding, fasttext

I am trying to create a **fasttext word embedding** using the following code.

```
import fasttext
from os import path
txt_path = path.join("/home/ccse/FastText_embeddings", "train.txt")
model = fasttext.train_unsupervised(txt_path, model='cbow')
```

here **train.txt** contains a single line - "Have a nice day."

After running the code, I get the following error:

```
Read 0M words
Number of words:  0
Number of labels: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ft_embedding.py", line 4, in <module>
    model = fasttext.train_unsupervised(txt, model='cbow')
  File "/home/ccse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fasttext/FastText.py", line 455, in train_unsupervised
    fasttext.train(ft.f, a)
ValueError: Empty vocabulary. Try a smaller -minCount value.
```

I don't understand the reason of it and how to fix it.

Additional information:
I am running- 
Ubuntu 18.04,
Python 3.6.8,
fasttext 0.9.1

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. I did a silly mistake. Leaving the solution here in case someone has done the same dumb mistake as mine.

Default value of minCount is set to 5. As my train file contained only 1 line with every word occurring only once, I was getting that error. 
To fix it, I just had to change the parameter value.

```
model = fasttext.train_unsupervised(txt_path, model='cbow', minCount = 1)
```

When creating embedding in real life (not for testing the functions), we will use large corpora. In that case we should not face this problem.